# how to get the status of DeleteUser when using Microsoft Graph API .Net Sdk

Tags: .net, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am looking at this sample here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-delete?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

await graphClient.Users["{user-id}"]
    .Request()
    .DeleteAsync();
```

It says: "If successful, this method returns 204 No Content response code. It does not return anything in the response body."

However, the signature for DeleteAsync() method is just a Task. When I call it, how can I get any information about whether the user was deleted or not?

Answer (score 1):

In the case of an error, `DeleteAsync` will throw `ServiceException` with an inner `Error` that contains the service error details. If the call succeeds it means that the user was deleted. As mentioned in the doc: ***If successful, it does not return anything in the response body.***

If you want to check what status code the request returns to be sure that response returns 204 you can send HTTP request using the .Net Microsoft Graph client library.

```
var requestUrl = client.Users["{user-id}"].Request().RequestUrl;

// create the request message
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Delete, requestUrl);

// authenticate HttpRequestMessage
await client.AuthenticationProvider.AuthenticateRequestAsync(request);
// it will call your IAuthenticationProvider you specified in ctor of GraphClient class
// and add Authorization header with access token to the request

// send the request and get the response
var response = await client.HttpProvider.SendAsync(request);

// read status code response.StatusCode
if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    throw new ServiceException(
        new Error
        {
            Code = response.StatusCode.ToString(),
            // read details why the user was not deleted
            Message = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
        });
}
```